# MYSQL Query works for current week not next

Tags: mysql, database, intervals

```
SELECT a.agent, a.talktime, a.percentclosed,COALESCE(COUNT(b.dealamount),0),COALESCE(SUM(b.dealamount),0) , b.dealdate
FROM closers a
LEFT JOIN deals b ON a.agent = b.agent
WHERE b.dealdate IS NULL OR YEARWEEK( b.dealdate ) = YEARWEEK( NOW( ) ) 
GROUP BY a.agent
ORDER BY COALESCE( SUM( b.dealamount ) , 0 ) DESC
```

Can anybody help me fix this query i know its messy but im new to this,

This works fine for the current week but if i add +1 to simulate a future week everybody who has a deal the week before does not show,

Thanks,

John,

IMAGE OF QUERY'S

[image]

Comment: Where did you add +1 and how?

Comment: please show your code, you're results, and what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

WEEKOFYEAR is not good in this case because it will wrap at year's end. You should use YEARWEEK().

```
WHERE b.dealdate IS NULL OR YEARWEEK( b.dealdate ) = YEARWEEK( NOW( ) ) +1
```

Comment: I tried it but still only the agents who have not had deals show i need everyone to show even if they dont have deals for the current week

Comment: This is different from what you're asking. If you need to show every agent, remove the condition on the week. Specify what should do your query.

Comment: I only display the current deals for this week the objective is that every agent has 0 deals and they all show for that current week

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what do you want to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: I am to display the results on a statistics page so i have the deals table and everytime an agent has a deal a record gets added into the deals table AGENT DEALTYPE DEALAMOUNT DEALDATE, I just want to display all of the agents that are listed in the closers table if they have deals or not they should still show

Comment: Here are the results i get with the query i first posted

http://i52.tinypic.com/69jsl2.png

Comment: I saw the pic. Are you sure that there are agents with deals in the next week? I don't see why the query should not work.

Comment: There are no deals in the next week it just needs to says the agent has 0 deals thats what i want anyway lol

Comment: So wait if you need it to display zero then use ISNULL around your count with your LEFT JOIN and it will show up zero instead of null

Comment: I just tried this but all agents are still not showing, Same as the image

Comment: SELECT a.agent, a.talktime, a.percentclosed,COALESCE(COUNT(b.dealamount),0) ,COALESCE(SUM(b.dealamount),0) , b.dealdate
    FROM closers a
    LEFT JOIN deals b ON a.agent = b.agent
   WHERE b.dealdate IS NULL OR YEARWEEK( b.dealdate ) = YEARWEEK( NOW( ) ) 
    GROUP BY a.agent
    ORDER BY COALESCE( SUM( b.dealamount ) , 0 ) DESC

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE b.dealdate IS NULL OR WEEKOFYEAR( b.dealdate ) = WEEKOFYEAR( date_add(NOW( ), interval 1 week))
```

use the interval feature of mysql, and the date_add or date_sub function

[Reference](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/date-add-mysql-intervals-dates/)

Comment: I tried that the got the same result, I need it to be the current week Monday to Sunday not the last 7 days

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work!,

```
SELECT a.agent, a.talktime, a.percentclosed, COALESCE( COUNT( b.dealamount ) , 0 )     ,COALESCE( SUM( b.dealamount ) , 0 ) , b.dealdate
FROM closers a
LEFT JOIN deals b ON a.agent = b.agent
AND WEEKOFYEAR( b.dealdate ) = WEEKOFYEAR( NOW( ) ) 
WHERE b.dealdate IS NULL 
OR WEEKOFYEAR( b.dealdate ) = WEEKOFYEAR( NOW( ) ) 
GROUP BY a.agent
ORDER BY COALESCE( SUM( b.dealamount ) , 0 ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```